# Command for inverse circumflex in text mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, text-mode

I would like to write this name that have an inverse circumflex above letter c: [image]

I have found the command `\check{c}`, but it is in math mode. I want to find something equivalent but in text mode, to make no difference with the other letter/words of the text. (Using `\check{c}`, I get this: [image])

Thank you!

Comment: the symbol is called a *hacek*, or, more properly, a *`ha\v{c}ek`*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The accent command here is `\v`, so you want `Ku\v{c}inskas`. You could of course use UTF-8 input and either `inputenc` with pdfLaTeX or a UTF-8 capable engine (XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX).

Comment: Table 17 in the [Comprehensive List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) lists the main accents available.

Comment: Thanks Joseph & egreg for your comments and solutions. Problem solved.